# changing inp by deleting element

Tags: python, abaqus

I am looking for a way to delete elements from abaqus inp. The analysis type is dynamic explicit and elements are S4R. 
I should notice that elements which should be deleted are updated in a matlab optimization cycle.
Is there any way except using subroutine VUMAT?(even python scripting is preferred)
any idea will appreciated.

Comment: What is abaqus inp - I do not have access to that software suite. Is this a special file, a section in a file, ... please provide. Why is it preferrable to **not** use the "subroutine VUMAT" - stating this might also help people to suggest solutions or directions where to further look for.

Comment: Excuse me,I want to delete elements from abaqus input file (*.inp).I I have gone through abaqus manula for element deletion in abaqus explicit.

Comment: You're welcome, maybe someone knowing the file format can help now.

Comment: Sorry again, I should add this comment to previous one. After going through abaqus manual, I understood that one way is using VUMAT subroutine. But I did not use it before, while I am familiar with python scripting in abaqus.Thank you in advance

Comment: Try manually deleting the elements in a text editor. Off hand I'm not sure what the consequences will be if you also need to, for example, track and delete dangling nodes, and so on, but if you can make it work by hand then you can write a python script to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reply. I tried your advice, I deleted the elements that I wanted to be removed from *.inp file. But when I imported the the *.inp, ABAQUS did not accept the file and gave error.
What I understood from your answer is that If I could not change *.inp file manually, It would not be possible to make change by python. 
Excuse me if I did not explain clearly. I think It is better to ask my question in this way:
I have an inp file containing a crash box simulation and dynamic explicit analysis applied on it.
I want this tube have some void elements before analysis. So I should manipulate the *.inp file. (This FE model will be used for topology optimization purpose in matlab)